# Update of extended mp3 tags in VBA MsAccess (Fieldnames needed)

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, mp3

Environment : VBA  Access 2007 - Win7
I am searching after the name of the field "composer" located in the tag of a mp3 file
I can read all the details of a (mp3)tag and change for example the modifydate

code :

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(FolderName)

If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
    Dim objFolderItem

    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(Filename)

    If (Not objFolderItem Is Nothing) Then
        Dim objInfo
        'next statement provides the "change date"
        objInfo3 = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 3)
    End If
    'next statement provides the "composer"
    objInfo220 = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 220)
    Stop
    'next statement updates the date changed value
    objFolderItem.modifydate = "01/01/2009 8:00:00 AM"

    'next statement doesn't work because of invalid name ??
    objFolderItem.composer = "xxxxxxxxxxx"


    objInfo = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 3)
    Stop
    Set objFolderItem = Nothing
End If
```

The name `objFolderItem.composer` doesn't work.
Which fieldname can I use to update the composer ?
Where can I find those names ?

Answer (score 0):

https://help.mp3tag.de/main_tags.html

TCOM is the field required. I have only posted this as I hate blind alley web pages.

All very old stuff should be answered or deleted if no longer relevant.